# How to autoconnect to a BLE device when app is not in foreground using rxandroidble?

Tags: rxandroidble

According to the docs:

> Unlike the native Android API, if autoConnect=true while using this
>   library there will be NO attempts to automatically reconnect if the
>   original connection is lost.

I'd like the phone/app to be connected when back in range even if the app is not being used when it happens, I don't really care about the app, just need the phone to be connected.

If I'm not mistaken, the native API would trigger a reconnection even if the app is not running as long as the devices are paired/bonded (is that assumption correct?).

How could I achieve this using RxAndroidBle? Is running a foreground service with an annoying sticky notification the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I'm not mistaken, the native API would trigger a reconnection even if the app is not running as long as the devices are paired/bonded (is that assumption correct?).

This assumption is not correct. You would still need the process which started the connection to be around.

> How could I achieve this using RxAndroidBle? Is running a foreground service with an annoying sticky notification the only way?

You have answered your question — the same statement is true when using the native API (which used by `RxAndroidBle` under the hood actually)